# How can I get all assets from my wallet?

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets

I need to get all assets/tokens from my wallet listed in an array on my smart contract if it's even a possible thing to do.I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71670989/easy-way-to-view-a-list-of-the-tokens-owned-by-a-user) but when i try to nothing happened

```
  pragma solidity 0.8.12;

contract GetWalletDemo {

 uint256 public tokenCounter ;
mapping(address => uint256) public balances;

mapping(uint256 => address) public _tokenOwner;
//mapping(uint256 => uint256) public _tokenOwner;

function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256) {    return balances[_owner];}
function ownerOf(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (address) {    address owner = _tokenOwner[tokenId];    require(owner != address(0));    return owner;}



   function ownerOfTokenIds(address tokenOwner) external view returns (uint256[] memory) {
        uint256[] memory result = new uint256[](balanceOf(tokenOwner));
        uint256 counter = 0;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            if (ownerOf(i) == tokenOwner) {
                result[counter] = i;
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a contract that read the balances from a list of tokens.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: ISC
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IERC20 {
    function balanceOf(address) external  view returns (uint);
}

contract BalanceChecker {
    function getBalances(address user, IERC20[] memory tokens) external view returns (uint256[] memory) {
        uint[] memory balances = new uint[](tokens.length);

        for (uint i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            balances[i] = tokens[i].balanceOf(user);
        }

        return  balances;
    }
}
```

The example has some issues

- it errors out when `tokens[i]` isn't an ERC20 contract
- it needs a list of tokens
- for a long token list it will use a lot of gas

An older more complete example is this contract: https://github.com/wbobeirne/eth-balance-checker/blob/master/contracts/BalanceChecker.sol